# How can i know the creation date of a sharepoint library? (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: library

How can I know the "Created" and "CreatedBy" fields of a SharePoint library? I am using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the library in browser
2. Activate the ribbon and choose "Open in Explorer"
3. Go one level up
4. Right Click the Library and Select Properties
5. Created Date will be displayed in the property window

Answer (score 1):

the below script will give you the Created date of List/library.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb “http://yourweburl”
$list = $web.lists[“Your List Name”]
$listCreatedDateTime = $list.Created
$web.Dispose()
$web = $null
Write-Host $listCreatedDateTime
```

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/08/06/get-created-date-for-sharepoint-list/

Also check this MSDN for more properties n Method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list_members(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Created date and Created By (Internal name `Author`) can be checked one of the tools like [SPManager](http://spm.codeplex.com/). However, if a code solution like PS is needed then the script by @Waqas can be used with one addition `$list.Author` to get created by information.